# How can I use a Material Design Icon as a CSS background-image value?

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I am using materializecss so I already have the material design icons available. How can I use them as `background-image` value in my CSS code (SASS actually)?

Comment: Looks like the docs show that SVGs are available, so you could probably do something like `background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg ...>[put SVG code here]</svg>`.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I was trying to import the font, but it seems it is not a proper css image value. Post this as an answer & I will close the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the Material Design Icons' SVG code to set a background-image, like so, for example:

```
.selector {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="%232196F3" d="M 5,3L 19,3L 20.7359,6L 20.7304,6C 20.9018,6.29149 21,6.63428 21,7L 21,19C 21,20.1046 20.1046,21 19,21L 5,21C 3.89543,21 3,20.1046 3,19L 3,7C 3,6.638 3.09618,6.29846 3.26437,6L 3.26135,6L 5,3 Z M 5.57294,4L 5,5L 5,5L 19,5L 18.4303,4L 5.57294,4 Z M 7,12L 12,17L 17,12L 14,12L 14,10L 10,10L 10,12L 7,12 Z "></path></svg>');
}
```

[A fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r65mr5qs/)

Quirks I noticed / was reminded of while making the fiddle:

- It doesn't seem to work without the xmlns attribute
- A `#` in the fill or elsewhere needs to be escaped with `%23` (or use the rgb(a) value instead)
- You may need to adjust width and height and viewBox attributes depending on your needs (whether to fill the area, repeat or not (which you can also affect with `background-repeat`), etc.)

Comment: Invalid property value

Answer (score 24):

Another technique you could use if you're using the Material Icons Font is making use of the `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors + `html entities`.

**CSS** [(codepen example)](https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/dzpNvo?editors=1100)

```css
    /* imports the font */
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");

    /* adds icon in front of the element */
    .someclass:before { 
        /* https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints */
        content: "\E3E7"; 
        font-family: "Material Icons"; 
    }
```

(here is the link to the [icon codes](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints))

It's not exactly a `background-image` but still could be useful.

Comment: Just to add more info...
Actually, just this chunk is necessary: `.someclass:before { content: "\E3E7"; font-family: "Material Icons";}`.    
The declaration `content: "\E3E7";` sets the codepoint of the icon to be used.    
For example, you can use the code `\E312` as value of the `content` property to get a keyboard icon.   
Available material design icons codepoints:
 https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints

Comment: dead link, maybe use: https://gist.github.com/AmirOfir/daee915574b1ba0d877da90777dc2181